# jQuery Mobile Change DropDown Selected Option and refresh it

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am writing jQuery Mobile App.
I am changing drop-down selected option via below statement:-
  $("#DataBaseNames").val(db);

I am sure about correct db value being passed, as i checked it via alert.
When I drill down the drop down, it also shows the correct text selected, but dropdown itself is not showing the correct text as selected.

Any refresh call I need to insert?

Edit:-Adding code, below answer from phill solved it

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

        $("#@ViewBag.DivTitle").live('pageshow', function () {

            var db = getCookie("DataBaseNames");

            $("#DataBaseNames").val(db);            
            $("#DataBaseNames option[value='"+ db + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

            //      refresh value , Following is what is required        
            $('select').selectmenu('refresh');

            $("#cmdLogOn").live("click", function () {
                var dbSelected = $("#DataBaseNames option:selected").text();              
                setCookie('DataBaseNames', dbSelected);
            });
        });

        function setCookie(name, value) {
          var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Code would be nice to look at, please edit your question and add some example code. Maybe http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> **refresh update the custom select**
>
> This is used to update the custom select to reflect the native select element's value.If the number of
> options in the select are different than the number of items in the
> custom menu, it'll rebuild the custom menu. Also, if you pass a true
> argument you can force the rebuild to happen.

```
//refresh value         
$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/forms/selects/methods.html

Answer (score 2):

I checked [this link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) and found it working for me. Try this:

```
var myselect = $("select#YourDropdownID");
myselect[0].selectedIndex =0;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change one dropdown based on another use this.

```
<link href="code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="jquery/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="../favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ItemNo()
    {
    var no = $('#sltItemNo')[0].selectedIndex;

    var myselect = $("select#sltItemName");
    myselect[0].selectedIndex =no;
    myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
    }
    function ItemName()
    {
    var no = $('#sltItemName')[0].selectedIndex;

    var myselect = $("select#sltItemNo");
    myselect[0].selectedIndex =no;
    myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
    }

</script>

<select id="sltItemNo"  onchange="ItemNo()" data-shadow="false" data-mini="true">
   <option value="Abc">1</option>
   <option value="Cde">2</option>
   <option value="Efg">3</option>
</select>

<select id="sltItemName"  onchange="ItemName()" data-shadow="false" data-mini="true">
   <option value="1">Abc</option>
   <option value="2">Cde</option>
   <option value="3">Efg</option>
</select>
```