# How to add options inside drop down Dynamically keeping the same style (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using Jquery Mobile

I made two drop down , on the basis on first drop down the second drop down value is fetched from database using Ajax call.

If i add values dynamically , the drop down boxes loses its css style...

Used Grid 2 column view for the drop down ....

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <div class="ui-grid-a">
     <div class="ui-block-a-list">
            <label for="p1" style="width:100%" >Type1:</label>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-block-b-list">
            <select id="partner" name="partner" data-icon="arrow-d" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="p1">1</option>
                <option value="p2">2</option>
            </select>
     </div>
  </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a-list">
                <label for="s2">Type 2:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b-list">
                <select id="specialist" name="specialist" data-icon="arrow-d" data-native-menu="false">
                    /* adding options dynamically using server side and ajax call */
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>
     </div>
```

Values are getting at the correct location but am not able to put the same css style effect as it used to be..

Comment: See this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153226/jquery-mobile-change-dropdown-selected-option-and-refresh-it

I think this resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [jQuery Mobile Doc](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html):

> If new list items are added to the list or removed from it, the dividers are not automatically updated: you should call refresh() on the listview to redraw the autodividers.

So try to add something like:

```
  $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

after you have populated the list.